# Catching a suspended message in BizTalk with System.Exception

Tags: webserver, try-catch, biztalk, faults

In my BizTalk orchestration I'm trying to catch a suspended Message to down web server.

I already caught an operation for server faults, my next task is to catch a message in the case when the web server is down. I'm currently using a System.Exception fault to catch the message, then I use the faultname. Message to insert the message into a logging table.

This process works, but the message also still suspends in BizTalk. Whats the next step to not have the message show as suspended in BizTalk since I already have the information I want harvested out of the fault and logged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Terminate shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Routing for Failed Message on the Port, and have another send port that subscribes to the error messages.

[Using Failed Message Routing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578516.aspx)

> The error-handling facility allows the designer to designate automated handling of messaging failures as an alternative to the traditional (now default) behavior of placing failed messages in the Suspended queue. This automated handling routes an error message to any subscribing routing destination, such as a send port or orchestration. The error message is a clone of the original message with all previously promoted properties now demoted and with selected properties related to the specific messaging failure promoted to the message context.